# Why some resharper menu items are unavailable (code cleanup, refactoring...)?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I tried to use code my code cleanup shortcut (Ctrl-E, F) but receive the following message:
The key combination (Ctrl-E, F) is bound to command (ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode) which is not currently available.

Then I noticed that some ReSharper menu items where actually grayed out. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

After a failed build due to StyleCop I clicked the link to the .cs file and forgot that I was examining a file not in the solution. If you go to the actual file in the solution (not the one coming from TFS), you'll be able to execute those commands again.